# Giving serial number with 4 digit long failed

Tags: c#, string

I have to get serial number that include `Member` that getting from the user and adding to the member serial number of **4** digit. 
if I got `888` the `newMemberId` will be `8880001`, and in the next loop `8880002` and so on, the problem is when getting to index of ten I will get `888010` with this code. why?

```
while (dbNof.AllMembers.Any(x => x.MemberId == newMemberId))
{
    numerator++;

    newMemberId = Member + 
                  numerator.ToString().PadLeft(5-numerator.ToString().Length, '0');
}
```

Comment: Try formatting - `Member + numerator.ToString("d4");` where `d4` stands for *at least* `4` *digits*

Comment: @Fildor: if `Member` is arbitrary string, say `"Something"` we can't do it  mathematically

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, I retracted my comment. I just realized that a) just what you said and b) we'd have to check if numerator is < 10000 which does not really make things more readable nor less complex. And also, the string interpolation is just both, easy and readable ... , so +1 for your answer.

Comment: The code doesn't work because PadLeft's argument is the total length of the padded string, not the number of characters to append, as you have assumed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want formatted output (at least `4` digits in your case) use formatting:

```
 newMemberId = Member + numerator.ToString("d4");
```

Or (string interpolation):

```
 newMemberId = $"{Member}{numerator:d4}";
```